# Problem running yugabytedb in Virtuozzo Container

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is it possible to run YugabyteDB in the Virtuozzo Container?
I am getting error at startup but don’t know how to resolve problem.
Is this error related to prerequisite checks as such failures are visible in the log?

```
$ ./bin/yugabyted start
Starting yugabyted...
/ Running system checks...yugabyted crashed. For troubleshooting, contact us on https://www.yugabyte.com/slack or check our FAQ at https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/faq/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/yugabyted", line 1621, in run
    args.func()
  File "./bin/yugabyted", line 254, in start
    self.start_processes()
  File "./bin/yugabyted", line 788, in start_processes
    prereqs_check_result = self.prereqs_check(ulimits=ulimits_failed)
  File "./bin/yugabyted", line 511, in prereqs_check
    check = self.linux_prereqs_check()
  File "./bin/yugabyted", line 473, in linux_prereqs_check
    transparent_hugepages = re.search("\[(.*)\]", transparent_hugepages_check[0]).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Outside of the container, YugabyteDB starts without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `yugabyted` cli is checking for hugepages and Virtuozzo container doesn’t have them. Try running the db manually and it should work.